# How to search using a delimited string as array in query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to search for records columns that match a value within a delimited string.

I have two tables that look like this

Vehicles

```
| Id | Make | Model |
|----|------|-------|
| 1  | Ford | Focus |
| 2  | Ford | GT    |
| 3  | Ford | Kuga  |
| 4  | Audi | R8    |
```

Monitor

```
| Id | Makes | Models   |
|----|-------|----------|
| 1  | Ford  | GT,Focus |
| 2  | Audi  | R8       |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
| Id | Makes | Models   | Matched_Count |
|----|-------|----------|---------------|
| 2  | Audi  | R8       | 1             |
| 1  | Ford  | GT,Focus | 2             |
```

Using the following query I can get matches on singular strings, but I'm not sure how I can split the commas to search for individual models.

```
select Id, Makes, Models, (select count(id) from Vehicles va where UPPER(sa.Makes) = UPPER(va.Make) AND UPPER(sa.Models) = UPPER(va.Model)) as Matched_Count
from Monitor sa
```

*(I am using a very SQL Server 2016 however I do not have access to create custom functions or variables)*

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple value sin a string.  Or, explain why you are stuck with such a bad data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are stuck with this data model,  you can use `string_split()`:

```
select m.*, v.matched_count
from monitor m outer apply
     (select count(*) as matched_count
      from string_split(m.models, ',') s join
           vehicles v
           on s.value = v.model and m.makes = v.makes
     ) v;
```

I would advise you to put your efforts into fixing the data model, though.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c66929c58dfb0491f147f274400f1e81) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I've tried to build this in sqlfiddle but I'm getting an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87402/1

Comment: @InvalidSyntax . . . I added a db<>fiddle.